# why for loop not working in django .Error in rendering html in django using for loop

Tags: python, django

i am writing code to get a carousal which consists of products using for loop in python
But there is some isuue it is generating everthing but not generating my items inside carousal
Things defined here:

```
list_of_range=[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

Now my no of slides in carousal is generated pretty well but items in side each slide is not get generated
Here's the code in index.html

```
<div class="container mt-5" >
      <div id="carouselContainer" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner justify-content-center">
          {% for i in list_of_range %}
          {% if i == list_of_range.0 %}
          <div class="carousel-item  active">
          {% else %}
          <div class="carousel-item ">
          {% endif %}
            <div class="row">
      {% for d in list_of_range.i %}

              <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem">
                  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRyRql003EXAw9EVs6V3koKd5wXbW0Lt-yJOA&usqp=CAU" class="card-img-top" alt="..." />
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">{{products.0.product_name}}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">
                      Some quick example text to build on the card title and make
                      up the bulk of the card's content.
                    </p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              {% endfor %}
            </div>
          </div>
          {% endfor %}
```

and the code in main.py is as follows :

```
def index(request):
    all_products_list = Product.objects.all()
    n= len(all_products_list)
    nslides = n//3+ ceil((n/3)-n//3)
    print(nslides)
    prod_range_list = []
    to_range = n
    for c in range(nslides):
        if to_range/3>=1:
            prod_range_list.append(list(range(c * 3, (c * 3) + 3)))
            to_range-= 3
        else:
            prod_range_list.append(list(range(c * 3, c * 3 + to_range)))
    print(all_products_list[0].product_id)
    print(prod_range_list)
    params = {
        'products':all_products_list,
        'no_of_slides':nslides,
        'range_slides':range(0, nslides),
        'class':'active',
        'no_in_each_slide': range(3),
        'last_slide_no':nslides-1,
        'list_of_range':prod_range_list

    }

    return render(request, 'shop/index.html', params)
```

Here there are 5 items in

```
all_product_list
```

i expected to get the 2 slides in carousal with 3 products in one and 2 in other but i am not getting a single product and all things inside row is empty in html generated

Answer (score 0):

`{% for i in list_of_range %}` : In the `i` variable you will get the array of elements (`[0, 1, 2]`) not the index.

`{% for d in list_of_range.i %}` : When you trying to access the `i` of `list_of_range`, it will be look something like this `list_of_range.[0, 1, 2]` which is invalid.

Instead try the following

```
<div class="container mt-5" >
  <div id="carouselContainer" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner justify-content-center">
      {% for range in list_of_range %}
        
      <!-- Checking it the first loop  -->
        {% if forloop.first %}
          <div class="carousel-item  active">
          {% else %}
          <div class="carousel-item ">
          {% endif %}

              <div class="row">
                <!-- We have the ranges in  range variable, then itreate over this-->
                {% for d in range %}
                  <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem">
                      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRyRql003EXAw9EVs6V3koKd5wXbW0Lt-yJOA&usqp=CAU" class="card-img-top" alt="..." />
                      ... Rest of your codes
                    </div>
                  </div>
                {% endfor %}
              </div>
          </div>
      {% endfor %}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```